# How do i bring an elemnt infront of mix blend mode?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anyone help me? mix blend is affecting my nav bar and a picture of the shoe. I want to bring them to the front. I tried with z-axis but it doesn't work.

```
<section>
    <img src="slike/bg.jpg" id="bg">
    <img src="slike/moon.png" id="moon">
    <img src="slike/mountain.png" id="mountain">
    <img src="slike/road.png" id="road">
    <img src="slike/road.png" id="road">
    <img src="slike/Untitled-1.png" id="shoe">
    <h1 id="text">AIRMAX</h1>
</section>
```

```
section{
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
   overflow: hidden;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;

}
section:before{
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100px;
   background: linear-gradient(to top, #0a2a43, transparent);
   z-index: 10000;

}

section:after{
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: #0a2a43;
   z-index: 10000;
   mix-blend-mode: color;

}

section img{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   object-fit: cover;
   pointer-events: none;
}
#text{
   position: relative;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 10em;
   z-index: 2;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 100px;
   font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}

#road{
   z-index: 2;
}
```

I made a parallax effect, so I have 5 images stacked on top of each other with mix blend mode. The sixth picture "untitled-1" should be on top of this blend mode. I don't know if this is possible so I came here for help. The blend mode is also affecting my nav bar but the nav bur is outside of the section that has bland mode on it.

Comment: Hello Samo!
+1 for already mentioning you tried the z-axis approach! Can you please add more details to the question. Sample structure, etc.

Comment: Hi, @Samo Fende - If you share you code here, It would be helpful.

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: how are you making the untitled on the top?

Comment: I put it as the last picture in the section so its at the top. I have a class that is affecting the "section" with mix blend mode. If i take the untitled image out of the section its puts it bellow the stacked images. If i leave it in it is affected by blend mode. I want to make it so that it is on top of the stacked images but not affected.

Comment: The context for all this is unclear, as a suggestion, Try a higher `z-index` on the shoe than the pseud-element adding the mix-blend.

Comment: Yes i know it would be easier if i could post pictured but i dont have 10 rep. Will try. Thanks